# Can any one tell me if the example I have mentioned is an example of a callback mechanism

Tags: c#

```
class B
{
     public delegate void CallBack();
     public event CallBacl cllBack;

     void Publish()
     {
       cllBack();
     }
}

class A
{
     B b = new B();
     b.cllBack += new CallBack(test_this)

     public void test_this()
     {

     }
}
```

1. Does the above example represent a way of implementing the call back mechanism in .net?
2. Or else do I need to use BeginInvoke and endInvoke for the call back mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of implementing a callback mechanism, and using delegates is indeed one of them.

See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thottams/archive/2007/11/01/calling-delegates-using-begininvoke-invoke-dynamicinvoke-and-delegate.aspx) for info on `begininvoke` etc. also see [that](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-the-lambda-operator) for an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, this is one method. Anyway I'll check this: `if (cllBack != null) cllBack();`
2. BeginInvoke (look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/0b1bf3y3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)) is used for asyncronous operations; the method you're using is the syncronous one.

Comment: example does it represent a observer pattern?

Comment: @Raghav55: Yes, events are effectively an implementation of the observer pattern.

Answer (score 0):

one caveat that it cost me some pain:

```
b.cllBack += new CallBack(test_this)
```

of course adds a reference to b in a, so even if you do not use b anymore in any other place, b is still referenced and will not be garbage collected.

what i think is a neater approach:

```
class A
{
    private delegate B.CallBack myCallBack;
    private B b = new B();

    public A
    {
       myCallBack = new B.CallBack( test_this );
       b.cllBack += myCallBack;
    }


   public void Close()
   {
     c.cllBack -= myCallBack;
   }
}
```

In short you register when you need the callback, and unregister when you no longer need the callback.

hth

Mario

PS: be careful, your b is local to the ctor